# Decode a string with unknown encode method

Tags: java, decode, sniffing

Here is an interesting (maybe), stupid (maybe) question. I got a string below:

```
w0nm%2BtHxOs8z%2FTyiLxWvNc8Rb%2B0Cnr%2FO5iHLktTyQ%2FmOq2YPNtDUJ8R%2BuEPwbajXq6rc2iWU0kKWFFquxKj%2BGw%3D%3D
```

I tried to convert HTML characters, and the string becomes:

```
w0nm+tHxOs8z/TyiLxWvNc8Rb+0Cnr/O5iHLktTyQ/mOq2YPNtDUJ8R+uEPwbajXq6rc2iWU0kKWFFquxKj+Gw==
```

still no clue what's about. From the pattern, it looks like base64 encoded. But after decode, the result is again meaningless:

`I:3</5o!Cf6'~Cm%BZ`

1. How do I know what's the content without knowing its encode method?
2. Which are the common decoding methods?

Comment: -->> HI Shivan, did u get the solution for this post, if so pls share with since i am also looking for the same thing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't get the answer so far.

Comment: Where did you get that string from? Information about the source might help with decoding it.

Comment: the source is from an online transaction, purchasing some online items.